# JavaScript event calendar not showing events in IE (working in Chrome)

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, events, fullcalendar

I am using A JavaScript event calendar from https://fullcalendar.io/. It works fine on chrome but not showing events in IE (11 version). Json Is returning from web method but events are not showing on the page.

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Event> GetEvents()
{
    List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Event ev = new Event();

        ev.EventID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["EventID"]);
        ev.EventName = dt.Rows[i]["EventName"].ToString();
        ev.StartDate = dt.Rows[i]["StartDate"].ToString();
        ev.EndDate = dt.Rows[i]["EndDate"].ToString();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i]["Location"].ToString()))
        {
            ev.Location = "--";
        }
        else
        {
            ev.Location = dt.Rows[i]["Location"].ToString();
        }
        ev.Description = dt.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString();
        events.Add(ev);
    }
    return events;
}




<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: "{}",
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("EventList.aspx/GetEvents")%>',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#fullcal').fullCalendar({
                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    $('#eid').html(calEvent.id);
                    $('#modalTitle').html(calEvent.title);
                    $('#msDate').html(moment(calEvent.start).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'));
                    $('#meDate').html(moment(calEvent.end).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'));
                    $('#mloc').html(calEvent.loc)
                    $('#mdesc').html(calEvent.des)        
                     $('#url').attr('href', 'Meetings/Meeting.aspx?ID=' + calEvent.id)                 
                    $('#fullCalModal').modal();

                },

                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                views: {
                    month: { // name of view

                        columnFormat: 'dddd',

                    },


                    week: { // name of view
                        titleFormat: 'MMMM  D , YYYY',
                        columnFormat: 'dddd D/M',

                    },
                    day: { // name of view
                        titleFormat: 'MMMM  DD  YYYY',
                        columnFormat: 'dddd D-M-YYYY',
                        // other view-specific options here
                        //displayEventEnd: true,
                        // timeFormat: 'H:mm'
                    }
                },

                //editable: true,
                displayEventTime: false,// hide event time 
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: $.map(data.d, function (item, i) {
                    var event = new Object();
                    event.id = item.EventID;
                    event.title = item.EventName;
                    event.start = new Date(item.StartDate);
                    event.end = new Date(item.EndDate);
                    event.loc = item.Location;
                    event.des = item.Description;
                    return event;
                }),

            });

            $("div[id=fullcal]").show();

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
});


</script>
         <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">
            <table id ="t1" class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><b>Start Date</b></th>
                <th><b>End Date</b></th>
                <th><b>Location</b></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td id ="msDate"></td>
                    <td id ="meDate"></td>
                    <td id ="mloc"></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
             </table>
             <table id ="t2" class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><b>Description :</b></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td id ="mdesc"></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
             </table>
          </div>
```

Comment: First set up IE debugging... Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages.". Save changes. to debug a web page in IE (not VS) open the website using IE (not f5 from VS), then press f12, to display the dev tool, the console tab will list any markup or security errors...possibly the data is received but IE can't display it because of markup errors.... correct those errors in your asp.net source... to debug client scripts, f12>debug tab, select "break on all exceptions" from the dropdown, (looks like a stop sign) then (!important) without closing the dev ..

Comment: cont... tool, return to your web page and either refresh the page or continue your testing. IE will now break at ANY scripting exception. You can also add break points with the dev tool to inspect local variables. remove the VS debugger calls from your client side scripts...eg. error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('failed to load json');//debugger;
        }.... Use the File>Properties menu in IE to make sure that your dev environment is not using the IE Intranet security zone (expected internet).